# Visual-studio-code Activity Bar displays incorrectly after opening a new project

Tags: visual-studio-code, alignment

[image]

I'm experiencing an issue with the Activity Bar in Visual Studio Code where it appears messed up whenever I open a new project. The icons and labels are not aligned properly, and it becomes difficult to navigate through the different sections.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Restarted Visual Studio Code.
Disabled all extensions and restarted.
Updated Visual Studio Code to the latest version.
Unfortunately, none of these steps have resolved the issue. I'm using VS Code on Windows 10. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any suggestions on how to fix this? I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see any misalignment.

Comment: If I change the alignment now, it is not saved when I open a new project.

Comment: show the before and after

Comment: same as the above, i also try to sync my settings after changing the layout.But it isn't working